# What do the colors of new posts mean?

Tags: support, tags, questions

I have read that the colors mean that they have my favorite tags in them like this:

[image]

But what about this?

[image]

I have favorite mysql tag but its white.

EDIT:

I have php, mysql, sql as favorites tags

Comment: That's because you are inside the page showing [tag:mysql] questions. No point highlighting ALL questions, right? :) So it's highlighted only if there is at least one other favorite tag.

Comment: added my favorites tags

Comment: i think you right , can you make it as an answer?

Comment: Related: [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that in your favorite tags you have [php](/questions/tagged/php) and not [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), seeing as both the questions tagged only "mysql" aren't shown in orange, while the one tagged "php" is.

It is also possible that you are on the page that lists questions [tagged mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql). In this case, the questions containing only mysql will not be highlighted, as then your entire page would be orange. Instead, only questions containing one or more of your other favorite tags will be highlighted.

*Edit:* As you mentioned, you have mysql, sql and php as favorite tags. So when visiting a page listing all questions tagged with mysql, only the questions which are also tagged "php" and/or "sql" will be highlighted.

Comment: edited my answer , and added my favorites tags

Comment: @user998158 Edited my answer to your specific case.

Comment: ok thx i think i get what u mean